# How to refactor an abstract class that has public members/properties for each concrete type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstraction, solid-principles

I am looking at some legacy code and have come across an abstraction that has properties for each of its derived/concrete types. I cannot share the exact code but please imagine that instead of it being a simple operation that there are numerous operations that are much more complex.

I have not come across anything like this before and have a lot of questions? First, is this a pattern that I am not aware of? If so, what is it? Second question, how should I refactor this so that it follows solid principles?

I will try my best to come up with a better example if needed.

```
public enum ToolType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    HRMonitor,
    Dumbell,
    SomeForceDevice
}

public abstract class ToolData
{
    private ToolData()
    {
        IsValid = false;
        this.ToolType = ToolType.Unknown;
    }

    public ToolData(ToolType toolType)
    {
        this.ToolType = toolType;
    }

    public ToolType ToolType { get; }
    public virtual bool IsValid { get; protected set; } = true;
    public double LinkQuality { get; set; }


    public NullToolDataValue NullData => this as NullToolDataValue;
    public DumbellDataValue DumbellData => this as DumbellDataValue;
    public HeartRateDataValue HRData => this as HeartRateDataValue;
    public SomeForceDataValue SomeForceData => this as SomeForceDataValue;
}

public class NullToolDataValue : ToolData
{
    public NullToolDataValue() : base(ToolType.Unknown)
    {
        IsValid = false;
    }
}

public class DumbellDataValue : ToolData
{
    public double WeightValue { get; private set; }

    public DumbellDataValue(double weightValue) : base(ToolType.Dumbell)
    {
        this.WeightValue = weightValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {

        return WeightValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public class HeartRateDataValue : ToolData
{
    public int HeartRate { get; private set; }

    public HeartRateDataValue(int heartRate) : base(ToolType.HRMonitor)
    {
        this.HeartRate = heartRate;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return HeartRate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public class SomeForceDataValue : ToolData
{
    public double LeftHandForceValue { get; private set; }
    public double RightHandForceValue { get; private set; }

    public int LeftHandPosition { get; private set; }
    public int RightHandPosition { get; private set; }

    public SomeForceDataValue(double lefthandValue, double rightHandValue, int leftHandPosition, int rightHandPosition) : base(ToolType.SomeForceDevice)
    {
        this.LeftHandForceValue = lefthandValue;
        this.LeftHandPosition = leftHandPosition;
        this.RightHandForceValue = rightHandValue;
        this.RightHandPosition = rightHandPosition;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{LeftHandForceValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}" +
            $"| {LeftHandPosition.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}" +
            $"| {RightHandForceValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}" +
            $"| {RightHandPosition.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}";                
    }
}
```

It is being used/consumed via something like the below which it too is missing some inheritance and things for brevity:

```
public class DumbellExcercise
{
    public void ToolDataReceived(ToolData data)
    {
        if (data?.DumbellData == null) return;

        //add value to some collection 
        Collection.Add(data.DumbellData.WeightValue);
    }

}

public class HRExcercise
{
    public void ToolDataReceived(ToolData data)
    {
        if (data?.HRData == null) return;

        //add value to some collection 
        Collection.Add(data.HRData.HeartRate);
    }

}
```

Comment: I certainly don't think abstract classes should 'know' about their implementations.. also, `new Penguin().ChickenManager.Fly()` - ugh.

Comment: I believe that 1) the properties themselves should be marked `[Obsolete("...", true)]`, 2) all call sites should be modified to use some form of pattern matching, thus eliminating the errors caused by (1), and 3) finally, the properties should be removed.

Comment: Not only should abstract classes not know about their implementations, as @stuartd said, but also a concrete class should not have a "has-a" relationship with itself (not even via its base class).

Comment: Obviously, this is wrong. However you're not really explaining why the abstract class (thinks it) needs those explicit descendant references rather than just using a virtual function, like `Fly()`.

Comment: @stuartd that will cause a null reference exception at runtime.

Comment: @NetMage hence, *"ugh"*

Comment: @madreflection, I have updated the example with the hope that it will better explain the situation. Thanks again for your time and efforts.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  I have updated the example with the hope that it will better explain the situation. Thanks again for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to give a shot at answering - hopefully this will help.

First up, ToolData shouldn't contain any References/Enums/whatever that list its subtypes.  So first on the chopping block: all the lambda properties that cast the object as a specific subtype.  I can kinda understand the appeal - you *know* an instance of ToolType happens to be a FloobieTool, so you call instance.FloobieTool and magically get a FloobieTool cast.  But... well, there are problems that come with it, not the least is that you're breaking Opened/Closed Principle.  Nothing wrong with making the person calling the class cast it explicitly with (FloobieTool)instance if they know they're working with a FloobieTool.

Next up: the ToolType.  Why do you need this?  You can *tell* if your instance of ToolData is a FloobieTool by simply doing an 'is' check in an IF condition:

```
void SomeFunc(ToolData toolData)
{
    if (!(toolData is FloobieTool)) throw new Exception("Non-Floobie!");
    // more code
}
```

I mean, what does that enumeration actually get you?  Because it has a definite cost: it has to be kept in-sync with the list of classes that implement ToolData.

Also, the part in ToolDataReceived() for each of those Exercise classes seems... weird.  I mean, you've got an exercise, and you're passing in ToolData.  Why are you storing the *amount* of the Dumbell exercise?  As opposed to just storing the ToolData.  I mean, you're going through quite a bit of testing/casting/etc, just to add the dumbbell *weight* to a Collection.  Any reason you can't just store the ToolData instance and call it a day?  If you *really* need to specifically store Dumbbell info, you could do something like:

```
public class DumbbellExercise
{
    List<DumbbellDataValue> dumbbellData = new List<DumbbellDataValue>();
    public void AddToolData(ToolData toolData)
    {
        if (toolData is DumbbellDataValue)
            this.dumbbellData.Add((DumbbellDataValue)toolData);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps - it's tough to go into too many details when we're working off an abstracted example of your actual problem  :-)

Comment: Thank you, it is pretty difficult to explain with full context. Further explanation is that our application interacts with physical devices so we created a communications library to manage the devices and essentially collect data. The main application uses the library to collect measurements. The goal, I think and still would be, is to use the same subscription method of collecting measurement data; even though each each device's measurement data can be different.

Answer (score 0):

Having seen your edits, I believe even more firmly that the way to refactor this code is to use pattern matching.  Pattern matching requires at least C# 7.0 so I'll include an almost-as-good way to do it pre-7.0 versions.

### Step 1

Mark the properties obsolete using `ObsoleteAttribute` and pass `true` for the `error` parameter.

```cs
[Obsolete("Use pattern matching instead.", true)]
public NullToolDataValue NullData => this as NullToolDataValue;

[Obsolete("Use pattern matching instead.", true)]
public DumbellDataValue DumbellData => this as DumbellDataValue;

[Obsolete("Use pattern matching instead.", true)]
public HeartRateDataValue HRData => this as HeartRateDataValue;

[Obsolete("Use pattern matching instead.", true)]
public SomeForceDataValue SomeForceData => this as SomeForceDataValue;
```

This will make it a compiler error to use them in any code processed by the compiler.  If you're doing any reflection on them, you'll get a runtime exception instead (after step 3 is complete) if you don't also change that code.

### Step 2

Modify every call site that uses those properties to use pattern matching instead.  If all you're doing is what you showed in the question, is should be as simple as this:

```cs
public class DumbellExcercise
{
    public void ToolDataReceived(ToolData data)
    {
        if (data is DumbellDataValue dumbell)
            Collection.Add(dumbell.WeightValue);

        // OR

        if (!(data is DumbellDataValue dumbell))
            return;

        Collection.Add(dumbell.WeightValue);
    }
}
```

The second variation is not as pretty because the condition has to be parenthesized before it can be negated (hey, at least VB has the `IsNot` keyword; go figure) but you get the same early return that the existing code has.

It looks like you're using at least C# 6.0 because you're using the null-coalescing operator (`?.`), but if you're not using at least 7.0, you can do this, instead:

```cs
public class DumbellExcercise
{
    public void ToolDataReceived(ToolData data)
    {
        DumbellDataValue dumbell = data as DumbellDataValue;
        if (dumbell != null)
            Collection.Add(dumbell.WeightValue);

        // OR

        DumbellDataValue dumbell = data as DumbellDataValue;
        if (dumbell == null)
            return;

        Collection.Add(dumbell.WeightValue);
    }
}
```

### Step 3

Remove the properties.  If there are no more compiler errors, the properties aren't being used, so you're free to get rid of them.

---

**Additional Note**

The `IsValid` property has a strange duality to it.  It can be assigned by the derived classes but it's also virtual so it can be overridden, too.  You really should pick one.  If it were my decision, I'd keep it virtual and make it read-only.

```cs
public abstract class ToolData
{
    // Continue to assume it's true...
    public virtual bool IsValid => true;
}

public class NullToolDataValue : ToolData
{
    // ...and indicate otherwise as needed.
    public override bool IsValid => false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is, more or less, the same idea I had but wanted to explore other possibilities. If I could, I would want to specify the return type when registering the function to get measurement data....idk ????  The application interacts with physical devices so we created a communications library to manage the devices and essentially collect data. The main application uses the library to collect measurements. Each device's measurement data can be different.